# Did the BJP deliberately flood Delhi, as alleged by the Aam Aadmi Party?

Tags: india, natural-disasters

**Background:** Delhi, the National Capital Territory of India, is currently flooded. Excess water upstream of Yamuna river is being released.

**Allegations:** Multiple senior politicians from Aam Aadmi Party, the political party ruling NCT of Delhi, have alleged that Bhartiya Janata Party (BJP), the political party heading Government of India, hates Delhi to the extent of flooding it deliberately. Like:

1. National Spokesperson and Rajya Sabha MP, [Sanjay Singh](https://twitter.com/SanjayAzadSln/status/1679510704527921154?t=qRH7N_KQsY-r18laq7emCg&s=19) alleging that the Hathini Kunj barrage is diverting Yamuna water to Delhi alone.
2. Sanjay Singh's statement has been echoed by the [party's verified handle](https://twitter.com/AamAadmiParty/status/1679799164019019777?t=-u8rEf5Fjs7j83jcthXF7g&s=19)
3. Earlier, [Saurabh Bhardwaj, MLA in Delhi Assembly, alleged](https://twitter.com/Saurabh_MLAgk/status/1679455552219529216?t=Cte6DWijEX1uaYxfihU0Jw&s=19) that the gates of ITO barrage are responsibility of Haryana govt (BJP ruled state) and these are not working properly due to poor maintenance.
4. Mr. Bhardwaj's statement is now being echoed by Delhi's CM, [Arvind Kejriwal](https://twitter.com/ArvindKejriwal/status/1679856784851492864?t=Dy_i2W_rGp27jco12THAdA&s=19) himself.

These are all serious allegations, and public has a right to get to the bottom of these. Citing news media reports alone will be deemed political (not neutral), so it will not be sufficient.

**Statement of Question**

Can someone cite the available official sources from the government of India or the state governments (Delhi, Haryana, Uttar Pradesh, etc) that throw light on what actually happened, and how these floods were handled?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site.  Questions about ongoing events are generally off topic here, see https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/handling-news-questions-about-current-events/2870#2870.

Comment: I'm curious why you think media reports are "not neutral", yet you would be willing to accept sources from the government, which is controlled by one of the parties in question?

Comment: From a skeptic's point of view: If one of the potentially guilty parties in this is the Indian government then official sources from the Indian government isn't the first place I'd look to throw light on the truth.

Comment: This question was posted on a different Stack Exchange @NateEldredge , which is still more suitable in my opinion. Given the history of this question, my opinion on whether this question is off topic here or not is rather pointless... About official sources, I'd point out that two governments controlled by two different Indian political parties are involved here, and they are/were sparring through news media and public social media on the matter. Media in itself is not a trustworthy in my opinion, unless they speak on basis of prior government records, duly citing them.

Comment: @LioElbammalf If a media trial is being conducted between two governments, prior official records are the only available arbiter of truth. Even if the matter goes to any neutral court, those will be the principal evidence.

Comment: @Madhur: There was an edit made to explain an acronym you used without defining it. You have rolled it back. The edit seemed perfectly reasonable, innocuous and improved the question - what was your objection to it?

Comment: If that acronym needs only defining, it is trivial to define it here itself.

Comment: @Madhur What do you mean? Isn't that what Danila was doing with their edit?

Comment: There are already too many links in the question. If we are defining one of the parties, we need to do the same with the other one as well. More links. More clutter.

Comment: "There are already too many links in the question." You're the one who put them there. Either some of those links aren't needed, in which case you can edit them out and add definition links for the political parties, or they're all needed, in which case there aren't "too many" links at all.

Comment: Those are links to the claims which form the subject of the question, while we are discussing here how much the question can be bulked up with background info. Well, I am text naming the governments the two parties are heading. Hope that'd suffice.

Comment: Yep, that should be enough. Thanks for the edit.